# $X^{-1/2}VX^{-1/2}$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Suppose $X \in S^{n}_{>0}$ $i$.$e$. positive definite, $V \in S^{n}$.i.e. symmetric. I'm curious if $X^{-1/2}VX^{-1/2}$ is diagonalizable or not?

This arises from $X+tV = X^{1/2}(I+tX^{-1/2}VX^{-1/2})X^{1/2}$. I think the matrix is not normal, but I suspect it is diagonal. However, I cannot prove this, and probably neglected something very simple.

Any hints?

---

Edit: The matrix is normal by definition. So this is of course true. I made a mistake before.

Comment: What is $S^n$? $ $

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm surprised this notation has not become popular. It means symmetric. I have edited the question

Comment: Symmetric as in "real, symmetric", or are you allowing complex?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Real, symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your matrices are symmetric.

Because $X$ is symmetric and positive definite, so is $X^{-1/2}$. Then you can use that if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is any real matrix,
$$
B^TAB\qquad\text{ is symmetric.}
$$
In your case,
$$
X^{-1/2}VX^{-1/2}=(X^{-1/2})^TVX^{-1/2}.
$$
And real symmetric matrices are orthogonaly diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you. And the matrix is normal, I don't know what I was thinking

Comment: Yes indeed. $ $